# Do I have to put all img tags inside figure tags?

Tags: html

My teacher told me that I have to put every image tag inside a figure tag.
After reading a lot, I understand that it's a good idea to put images that explain the content inside a figure tag, but I don't understand why I should do the same for all images such as image decoration, logo, etc.

```html
<h1>My super friend <img href="small-heart.jpg" alt=""><h1>
```

This is just an example, but if I want to show a small heart in the sentence, it seems ridiculous to put it in a figure tag.

Should I put all image inside figure tag?

If "yes" can you explain to me why?

Thank you.

Comment: For this particular instance I wouldn't use an image at all when you can just use [unicode](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-1.0/) ❤️

Comment: No, you should not put *all* `<img>` tags inside `<figure>` tags. Especially not ones inside a `<h1>`.

Comment: More important: you should not leave the `alt` text empty

Comment: @Bergi — Leaving `alt` empty is entirely sensible if the image is decorative or just reinforces information already in the text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 4):

Simply: No, you don't have to.

More precisely: like you said, img tags for logos or simple decorations or in a gallery don't have a need to be wrapped by a figure. If you look at the internet and the code of sites, you will find very few figure tags.

If you have a long text or article which contains images, a figure makes a lot of sense. Especially with a [figcaption](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp) tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: No problem! Just give it an up vote :)

Comment: I did it already ;-)

Comment: but why in a long text?

Answer (score -1):

Figure tag is like a picture in a book that has a caption under it. You can stick an `<img>` tag anywhere you want. One thing to consider is you can use an icon tag and use CSS to add the image, or you can use CSS to add an image to the `:before` or `:after`.

For example

```
h1:after { background-image: 'heart.jpg';}


<h1>Some Text</h1>
```

And the CSS would put the heart image after the closing `h1` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !